# whether creating object repeatedly affect java performance?

Tags: java, performance, swing, desktop-application

I use a jtabbedpane. for each tab it will have a panel and some components.
to increase the performance i created a 'n' number of function for 'n' number of tabs. in that function i created components for that tabs.if the particular tab get  selected i call the required function. so the component was created according to the tab selection. my question is

**first we select tab1[component was created for tab1]then  we change the tab from tab1 to tab2[component was created for tab2] if we again go to tab1 the component was created again. whether it affect performance? if yes.. how do i recover it?**

Comment: be sure that not possible to give you the answer to question of this nature, for better help sooner post an SSCCE demonstrated issue with tabs

Comment: never-ever add complexity by arguing with _assumed_ performance penalty. In your context: fully create, configure and add the n-tabs. If that introduces performance issue, _measure_ it to find the bottleneck, then proceed to fix that neck, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your re-creating the tabs each time, you're going take a performance hit when you switch tabs. While lazy loading is a good idea, it might be preferable to cache the results; so if the tab's content has already been created, you don't need to recreate it again.

You will need to profile the cost in performance against the memory usage over time.